# Snowflake sequence max value and Cycle

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am trying to create a sequence in snowflake with max value and cycle.
However I am not able to find any document where it says how to provide the max value.
But again I see in doc it says Snowflake will throw error if threshold is reach.

Can somebody please suggest how to create the below sequence in snowflake.

```
create or replace sequence myseq as bigint
start with 10000
increment by 1
no min value
maxvalue 2000000
no cycle;
```

And If any body can suggest what is the max value of sequence in snowflake. If I create it without datatype.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is here:

*A sequence value can represent a 64-bit two’s complement integer (-2^63 to 2^63 - 1). If the internal representation of a sequence’s next value exceeds this range (in either direction) an error results and the query fails. Note that this may result in losing these sequence values.*

This is mentioned on Snowflake docs [here](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/querying-sequences.html#sequence-semantics).

Answer (score 0):

Snowflake doesn't support cycling of sequences

Answer (score 0):

just do a modulus on the number + 1

```
CREATE OR REPLACE SEQUENCE SEQ_1 START = 10000 INCREMENT = 1; 
select mod(SEQ_1.nextval,2000000)+1
```